# Can I activate a signal (flag) in a process and it will respond in a concurrent process?

Tags: vhdl, fpga

I have a flag that activates in one process and I would like that a concurret process respond to this activation.

send_data is a bit signal:

```
    signal send_data:std_logic:='0';
```

```
 process
 begin
 wait until send_data='1';
 ...
 end

 process(enumer)
 begin
 ...
 send_data<='1';
 ...
 end process;
```

Comment: In what context? this is legal VHDL. But are you expecting it to synthesise? I would recommend you dont use this construct for synthesisable VHDL.

Comment: IEEE Std 1076-2008 14.2 Elaboration of a design hierarchy "The elaboration of a design hierarchy creates a collection of processes interconnected by nets; this collection of processes and nets can then be executed to simulate the behavior of the design." 14.7.3.4 Signal update "A *net* is a collection of drivers, signals (including ports and implicit signals), conversion functions, and resolution functions that, taken together, determine the effective and driving values of every signal on the net." Processes communicate via signal updates of elaborated nets when executing simulation cycles.

Comment: Your incomplete snippet examples isn't sufficient to determine that what you envision is functional. You've asked a yes or no question with the answer being yes. See [Where is the line for yes/no questions?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/258630/where-is-the-line-for-yes-no-questions)

Answer (score 0):

Generally:

You can write a Signal in one process and read it in multiple other processes.

For your application:

You can set `send_data` to '1' whilst waiting for it in another process, then set a signal like `send_flag_encountered` to '1', then reset `send_data` in the first process and then reset the `send_flag_encountered` in the second process.

This is even synthesizable. When doing this, I would recommend you to use FSMs.